# Swift - Check if at least three text fields are filled in

Tags: ios, swift

I need to check, using Swift, if my form has at least 3 text fields filled in, above my form example

```
1: name 1 surname 1

2: name 2 surname 2

3: name 3 surname 3

4: name 4 surname 4

5: name 5 surname 5
```

please note that fields have to be connected, for example, if name 4 is entered then it must also be entered surname 4.

Comment: What have you tried? That is a very basic task consisting only of straight forward coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job

```
var name1: UITextField!
var surname1: UITextField!
var name2: UITextField!
var surname2: UITextField!
var name3: UITextField!
var surname3: UITextField!
var name4: UITextField!
var surname4: UITextField!
var name5: UITextField!
var surname5: UITextField!

let list = [(name1, surname1), (name2, surname2), (name3, surname3), (name4, surname4), (name5, surname5)]
let populatedPairs = list.filter {
    $0.0?.text?.characters.count > 0 && $0.1?.text?.characters.count > 0
}
if populatedPairs.count > 2 {
    // your stuff goes here
}
```

### Update

You could also define a `isValid` function.

E.g. if you want the text in the field to have at least 3 chars your can

```
func isValid(name:UITextField?, surname:UITextField?) -> Bool {
    return name?.text?.characters.count > 2 && surname?.text?.characters.count > 2
}
```

Feel free to add your custom logic inside the body of the function.

This is how you pass the function to the `filter` method.

```
let validPairs = list.filter(isValid)
```

Comment: What if the text is `""`? :p

Comment: @appzYourLife: is there a way to make other checks over the filled in fields? E.g. checking that the field has a certain length.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more straightforward solution. I will call surname1 textfield as `s1`, name1 textfield as `n1` etc. (because I'm lazy...)

```
let nameEntered: [Bool] = []
nameEntered.append(n1.text!.trim() != "" && s1.text.trim() != "")
nameEntered.append(n2.text!.trim() != "" && s2.text.trim() != "")
nameEntered.append(n3.text!.trim() != "" && s3.text.trim() != "")
nameEntered.append(n4.text!.trim() != "" && s4.text.trim() != "")
nameEntered.append(n5.text!.trim() != "" && s5.text.trim() != "")

let enteredCorrectlyCount = 0
for isCorrect in nameEntered {
    enteredCorrectly += isCorrect ? 1 : 0
}

if enteredCorrectlyCount >= 3 {
    // do stuff
}
```

Where `trim` is defined as

```
extension String {
    func trim(str: String) -> String {
        return str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " \t\n\r\0"))
    }
}
```

Benefits of this method:

- Most importantly, it *works*.
- It is straightforward, easy to understand.
- It handles the case where the user only enters spaces.

Comment: good answer, is there a way to make other checks over the filled in fields? E.g. checking that the field has a certain length.

Comment: You mean checking the _text_ of the field having a certain length? Just use `n1.text!.characters.count` to get the length and use an if statement to check it. @Mono.WTF